# Displaying preloaded image (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I'm trying a basic display of a preloaded image with p5.js library (instantiation mode):

```
var sketch = function(p) {
    var fondo;
    p.preload = function() {
        fondo = p.loadImage('app/themes/mrg/dist/images/tramas/example.jpg');
    };
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    p.setup = function(){
        canvas = p.createCanvas(viewportWidth, 200);
        canvas.background(255);
        canvas.image(fondo, 0, 0);
    };
};
new p5(sketch);
```

The canvas was created but no image is there.

Here is a working example:
https://stage.margenesdelarte.org/

The canvas is at the end of the page (with white background) but no image is rendered inside.
Image path is right, since there is no error in the console and it can be reached in its place:

https://stage.margenesdelarte.org/app/themes/mrg/dist/images/tramas/example.jpg

What is wrong, and how can I display this image? Thanks!

Comment: Did you see in Network panel a request for that image?

Comment: Not, indeed. There is no request for that image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct version? (I used BASE64 because I didn't want to run a local server)

```
var sketch = function(p) {
    var fondo;
    p.preload = function() {
        fondo = p.loadImage("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhMAAwAPAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAMAAwAAAC8IyPqcvt3wCcDkiLc7C0qwyGHhSWpjQu5yqmCYsapyuvUUlvONmOZtfzgFzByTB10QgxOR0TqBQejhRNzOfkVJ+5YiUqrXF5Y5lKh/DeuNcP5yLWGsEbtLiOSpa/TPg7JpJHxyendzWTBfX0cxOnKPjgBzi4diinWGdkF8kjdfnycQZXZeYGejmJlZeGl9i2icVqaNVailT6F5iJ90m6mvuTS4OK05M0vDk0Q4XUtwvKOzrcd3iq9uisF81M1OIcR7lEewwcLp7tuNNkM3uNna3F2JQFo97Vriy/Xl4/f1cf5VWzXyym7PHhhx4dbgYKAAA7");
    };
    var viewportWidth = 500;
    p.setup = function(){
        var canvas = p.createCanvas(viewportWidth, 200);
        canvas.image(fondo, 0, 0); // doesn't work
        p.image(fondo, 0, 0);      // works fine
        console.log(p.image, canvas.image); //there are different functions
    };
};
new p5(sketch);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPENXx?editors=1111

Explanation:
Both `p` and `canvas` has a `image` function but there are different image functions. You have to use `p.image()`. I think `canvas.image()` is has some relations with https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image, but that's only my assumptions.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but please add an explanation about **why** it's the correct answer instead of just dumping some code without an explanation.

Comment: It works, so, thank you anyway. I gess that I can't store the canvas as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file being localhosted? For p5 to access local files such as images, it needs to be localhosted... I recommend apache